# How to trigger a GitHub action with curl

Tags: github

I want to trigger the following GitHub action:

https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/blob/master/.github/workflows/service-worker-test.yml

I have added the following to my `service-worker-test.yml`, which should allow curl to trigger it:

```
on:
+  repository_dispatch:
+    types: service-worker-test
```

I generated a `GITHUB_TOKEN` with `repo` permissions:

[image]

I then run curl:

```bash
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" --request POST --data '{"event_type": "service-worker-test"}' https://api.github.com/repos/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/dispatches
```

Results:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event"
}
```

I have read :

1. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow
2. https://goobar.dev/manually-trigger-a-github-actions-workflow/
3. https://blog.knoldus.com/trigger-a-github-action-with-an-http-request
4. https://kontent.ai/blog/how-to-trigger-github-action-using-webhook-with-no-code/

Appart that none of those tutorial agrees on the `Accept` headers, I did exactly what it is requested.

Also, there is a non understanding point, I will have to add payload to the curl request, and:

- `workflow_dispatch` use `event.inputs.versionFrom`
- `repository_dispatch` use `events.client_payload.versionFrom`

This will complexify the GitHub action, isn't there a way to simply use the same for both trigger method?

Does anybody what this errors means and how to achieve a trigger of the workflow using `curl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Not Found` was because I needed to have the scope `repos` write access, and not just read.

In order to use both `workflow_dispatch` and `repository_dispatch` with `inputs` and `client_payload` so that I can run the pipeline from cURL and GitHub UI, I needed to concat both placeholders like so:

```yaml
name: example-client-payload-action
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: webhook

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - run: 'echo "field: ${{ github.event.client_payload.foo }}${{ github.event.inputs.foo }}"'
      - run: 'echo "payload: ${{ toJson(github.event.client_payload) }}${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}"'
```

This way, one is interpolated as an empty string, and the second as the replaced value.

It's not very nice to read, but I am sure you can improve readability by doing the concat in an environment variable if you prefer.